# Laravel 5.4 - Getting number of records fitting a filter

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I have search page that searches for Job Openings.

it has this filters in it:

1. Location (country)
2. Gender
3. Job Type
4. Sector Category
5. Nationality

What is the most efficient way to tally how many on the search results fall into these filters?

say for example I search Job Openings for "web developer" that gives me 150 search results.

How can I tally how many in that 150 are located in the US, or Philippines, how many are Male exclusive jobs or open to any, or how many are for Americans, Germans, Filipinos?

Answer (score 1):

You can either add specific queries using the sql `count` method to sum up your required or solve it by using Laravel Eloquent´s [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections#available-methods). For example you could combine the `groupBy` and `count` function to get the required numbers.